# Bookmarklet do something after loading is finished

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Hi I am developing crawling program with bookmarklet in Chrome.

I want to crawl web page periodically and parse html page.
Web page can be reloaded every 5s, but page loaded alert is not executed.

here is my code

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
   console.log("page loaded");
});

function happycode(){
    alert('page loaded');
 }



setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Reloading....");
    window.onload=happycode ; 
    open(location.href, 'otherWindow')


}, 5000*1)
```

How can I parse and crawl webpage using bookmarklet?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page the javascript is no longer executed. You would need to convert this to a content script or a tampermonkey script to have it run each time after the `DOMContentLoaded` event.